# Why jpype doesn't work?

Tags: java, python, jvm, jpype

I have got python 2.7 installed on my PC (Windows), and I need jpype to use some Java methods of classes in .jar libraries.

So I installed `JPype-0.5.4.2.win32-py2.7.exe` that I found on the project's [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpype/files/JPype/0.5.4/).

After installing it, I tried that piece of code :

```
from jpype import *

print("Debug 1")
startJVM("C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client/jvm.dll", "-ea")
print("Debug 2")
java.lang.System.out.println("JPYPE WORKS !")
print("Debug 3")
shutdownJVM()
print("Debug 4")
```

But when I run it, it outputs just my `Debug x` lines...

When I try to run it on **PyScripter**, I still have the same output, but then it shows me 2 errors messages pop-up :

```
Error in getting the namespace of globals
```

and

```
Remote Server is not connected. Please reinitialize or disconnect the remote interpreter.
```

That's all. I don't understand why it doesn't work. Even without the `java.lang.System.out.println` line I have the same error pop-ups.

Maybe it's a problem with rights on the **jvm.dll** file, since it's my professional PC, but I can't tell.

Comment: Install the version from here and try again: https://github.com/originell/jpype, or actually just `pip install jpype1`

Comment: @kutschkem Still the same error. ^^

Comment: @kutschkem `pip install jpype1` ? I'm new to python, what's pip ? ^^'

Comment: pip is a package manager for python, think maven/maven-central. jpype1 is the name of the jpype version I linked to.

Comment: Is pip installed by default with Python 2.7 ? I used to make some python scripts on linux but it seems a bit more complicated on Windows. ._.

Comment: At least the second error doesn't sound like it has something to do with jpype. In addition, I just tried your code with 64-bit python 2.7, on Windows, with jpype1, and it worked, i got output from the call to System.out.println. Try again without PyScripter, maybe just on the command line. I suspect the errors come from PyScripter, not the program.

Comment: And no, pip does not come with python by default.

Comment: Didn't work with PyScripter, didn't work with IDLE, but it curiously worked with windows' CLI (cmd)...

Comment: @Malik Can you please share a working sample of executing class' function of a jar from Python using Jpype. I was not able to find a working sample, tried a couple of with options but fail with error 'not callable'